# Humidity and Snake Plants

Tags: houseplants, humidity

I've got a snake plant living in my room. I also have a gecko. A few days ago I turned on my humidifier and closed all doors/windows to raise the humidity to help my gecko with shedding. However, I've noticed that one of the leaves on my snake plant is turning yellow along the middle and bottom. I haven't watered it since, and I can't quite figure out what to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that one day or two of high humidity would harm your snake plant.  So nice for the gecko, that humidity really helps.  Yellow leaves have numerous causes, could very well be you are overwatering.  Please tell us more about your plant:  Where you live, is this guy in the house full time, does he have a very stable spot, have you fertilized and if so what and how long ago, how do you determine when to water?  How big is this pot in relation to your plant?  Raising the humidity would not hurt this plant especially for a day or two?

What soil did you use in the pot with your snake plant?  Sterilized potting soil without any fertilizer added to the soil or any water holding gimmicks, sponges or gels?

Get used to the heft of the plant and pot when watered.  When that plant needs watering again that heft/weight is markedly lighter.  Only water when the pot feels vastly lighter than what it feels after having just been watered.  Always dump the excess water from the saucer, do you have a drainage hole, that kind of thing?

Comment: I don't water very often, I live in central Alberta, he's in the house full time, stable spot, have not fertilized yet as it's getting to be colder, I water a few days after I water my succulents which I do about every 3 weeks. Sterilized potting soil, no fertilizer. I do have a drainage hole. Thinking about it, I'm wondering if the plant grabbed extra water from the humidity in the air, as it was very humid. I admit though, I don't know too too much about snake plants.

Comment: You certainly earn your name, Azalea!  You have the basics down pat!  Plants are tougher than we think.  A few days of abnormal humidity would NOT cause the soil to be too wet.  If anything your Sansevieria LOVED the vacation.  Sanseveiria is one of the toughest of the house plants.  Please send a picture.  It is good you know to not fertilize in the winter but in the home the seasons are a bit misleading.  Less light = Less fertilizer.  Indoor plants need a little NPK to get through the winter months as the environment is more artificial than out of doors gardens.

Comment: The soil in high humidity is less able to evaporate.  Then it stays more moist longer.  Like a human in Texas with 90% humidity.  Too much moisture in the air inhibits the evaporation process.  Moisture changing from liquid to gaseous is the mechanism for cooling our bodies...fans, moving air, dry air or low humidity are important to keep us humans from boiling our organs and brain.  Plants love high humidity and high amounts of CO2 in the atmosphere.  The problem is fungus loves this as well.  A few days of high humidity is not at all a problem...could be just an OLD leaf?

Comment: thank you for the advice on fertilization, by the way. i will keep that in mind. i doubt it was an old leaf, as it appeared yellow quite suddenly and it was directly after i turned the humidity up. i will try and get a picture soon